# Play framework: get value from Form

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

In Play! Framework, I have a form `Form[Device]`

For input values I use `@testarea`

```
@textarea(deviceForm("model"), '_label -> "Model", '_help -> "")
    @textarea(deviceForm("distributor"), '_label -> "Distributor", '_help -> "")
    @textarea(deviceForm("os"), '_label -> "Manufacturer", '_help -> "")</code>
```

How can I just get a value from form and print it? Not in the input filed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just call .value on it like so:

```
@deviceForm("distributor").value
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public Result hello() {
        DynamicForm requestData = formFactory.form().bindFromRequest();
        String model = requestData.get("model");
        String distributor = requestData.get("distributor");
        String os = requestData.get("os");
        return ok(model + distributor + " " + os);
    }
```

Assumption :

- You are using Play-Java
- your data not related to Model i.e you don't want to save it to database, you just want to gets its values.

please have a look at official [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaForms).

Comment: OP is clearly asking how to do this in the view, not the controller.